# Python FFT: freq shift

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft, frequency-analysis

While doing spectral analysis of a signal, I encountered a strange issue that the plotted signal frequency is shifted (or doubled). Here is a simple example showing my approach: a 1kHz sinusoidal signal is sampled with 100kHz. In the end, the signal bin appears at 2kHz instead of 1kHz.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_step = 1.0/100e3
t = np.arange(0, 2**14) * time_step

sig = np.sin(2*np.pi*1e3*t)

sig_fft = np.fft.rfft(sig)

#calculate the power spectral density
sig_psd = np.abs(sig_fft) ** 2 + 1

#create the frequencies
fftfreq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(sig_psd), d=time_step)

#filter out the positive freq
i = fftfreq > 0

plt.plot(fftfreq[i], 10*np.log10(sig_psd[i]))
plt.xscale("log")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function to compute the frequencies. FFT transforms of real signals have negative frequency components that are complex conjugates of the positive ones, i.e., the spectrum is Hermitian-symmetric. `rfft()` makes use of that fact and does not output the negative frequencies, just the DC component and the positive ones. Consequently, `sig_psd` is twice as short as what you'll get if you use `fft()` instead of `rfft()` and passing it to `fftfreq()` effectively doubles the frequencies.

Solution: use `rfftfreq()` instead.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_step = 1.0/100e3
t = np.arange(0, 2**14) * time_step

sig = np.sin(2*np.pi*1e3*t)

sig_fft = np.fft.rfft(sig)

#calculate the power spectral density
sig_psd = np.abs(sig_fft) ** 2 + 1

#create the frequencies
fftfreq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(sig), d=time_step)  # <-- note: len(sig), not len(sig_psd)

#filter out the positive freq
i = fftfreq > 0  # <-- note: Not really needed, this just removes the DC component

plt.plot(fftfreq[i], 10*np.log10(sig_psd[i]))
plt.xscale("log")
```